# Problem with uploading file .NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, insomnia

I'm trying to upload file (just .jpeg image) and save it on my server. I've written the following code for this:

#### Db context

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public ApplicationContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Recipes");
    }

    public DbSet<FileModel> Files { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

#### Model

```
public class FileModel
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

#### Method of my controller for uploading

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> AddFile(IFormFile uploadedFile)
    {
        string path = "";

        if (uploadedFile != null)
        {
            // путь к папке Files
            path = "/Files/" + uploadedFile.FileName;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await uploadedFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            FileModel file = new FileModel { Name = uploadedFile.FileName, Path = path };
            _applicationContext.Files.Add(file);
            _applicationContext.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The the next step that I'm going to do is testing it with the help of [Insomnia rest client](https://insomnia.rest/). I had setted up all acording to Insomnia documentation (to passing multipart/form-data header) and sent request. But in the `uploadedFile` I see null.

Here is screenshot of Insomnia
[image]

And screen of the result: 
[image]

Why `uploadedFile` is null? Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter name in your client is `image` not expected `uploadedFile` defined in Controller action

Comment: Thank you. Works!

Comment: Its easily to miss. Please dont forget to accept this as solution.

Comment: Yes it's a few uncomfortable after php for me)) Thank you for fix)